# Laravel: How to get ID from Papers Table to Store in Bookmarks Table

Tags: php, laravel, database

I can't get the PaperID to store into my Bookmarks DB

here is my controller for the bookmark store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'BookmarkName' => 'required',
        ]);

        $paper = DB::table('papers')
            ->where('PaperID', '=', $request->paper_id)
            ->value('PaperID');
        

        $bm = new Bookmarks();
        $bm->BookmarkName=$request->BookmarkName;
        $bm->paper_id = $paper;

        $bm->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Bookmark Added');
    }
```

here is the form to call the function

```
<form class="bookmarkInput" action="{{ route('Bookmarks')}} " method="POST" >
                            @csrf
                            <div class="group">      
                                <input class="inputInfo" type="text" name="BookmarkName" required>
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label class="infoLabel">Bookmark Name</label>
                            </div>

                            <br>
                            <br>

                            <button class="redBtn" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </form>
```

here is the route for it

```
Route::post('/Bookmarked', [App\Http\Controllers\BookmarkController::class, 'store'])->name('Bookmarks');
```

I do not know why it isn't getting the ID calling papers DB seems good but it doesn't want to get the current ID of the paper I want to bookmark

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where is `paper_id` supposed to come from? there is no form input or route parameter for it

Comment: @lagbox paper_id is a foreign key in the Bookmarks table to fetch the primary key of the papers table. Should I put like $paper->PaperID to the form action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing **paper_id** from **form**.

That's why your     ->where('PaperID', '=', $request->**paper_id**)
don't have value of paper_id.

you can pass paper_id from form by using **hidden** input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="paper_id" value = {{ $paper_id }}>
```

**Remember** to **pass paper_id variable** containg paper_id value to the blade having form.

Also add **->first()** before ->value('PaperID').